# Why does the child process behave differently when exec is supplied an invalid command?

Tags: c, process

```
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork(); //Two processes are made
        const char* ptr = secondlinecopy;
        if (pid > 0 && runBGflag==0) //Parent process. Waits for child termination and prints exit status
        {
            int status;
            if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) == pid && WIFEXITED(status))
            {
                printf("Exitstatus [");
                for (int i = 0; i < noOfTokens; i++)
                {
                    printf("%s ", commands[i]);
                }
                printf("\b] = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            }
        }
        else if (pid == 0)  //Child process. Executes commands and prints error if something unexpected happened
        {
             printf("why does this only print when an invalid command is supplied?");
             if (runBGflag==1) insertElement(getpid(),ptr);
             execvp(commands[0], commands);
             printf ("exec: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             exit(1);
        }
```

In the code excerpt we see a process creation via fork(). When execvp is supplied a real command, such as "ls" for example, we get the output.

```
/home/kali/CLionProjects/clash/cmake-build-debug: ls
clash      CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  Testing
clash.cbp  CMakeFiles      Makefile
Exitstatus [ls] = 0
```

However, if we supply an invalid command, the output will be:

```
/home/kali/CLionProjects/clash/cmake-build-debug: sd
why does this only print when an invalid command is supplied?exec: No such file or directory
Exitstatus [sd] = 1
```

Why is that the case? Shouldnt the process **always** call printf("Why does ...") first and then run exec?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that the case? Shouldnt the process always call printf("Why does ...") first and then run exec?

Let's say it works like this:

```
printf(...) --> internal buffer --(fflush? newline? max_buffer_size?)--> output
```

Usually `stdout` is line buffered and your `printf` has no newline. The data to-be-printed are stored inside some internal buffer. When `exec`-ing the `stdout` is not `fflush`ed and the parent process is replaced by child process as it is as a whole - so all the data stored in parent process, including some internal `stdout` state, are removed. When `exec` fails, `stdout` is flushed when you `printf(...\n"` (or after calling `exit()` when `stdout` is block buffered) and the data show up. Research: studio buffering modes [and `setvbuf()` function](https://man.archlinux.org/man/setvbuf.3.en).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that the case? Shouldnt the process **always** call printf("Why does ...") first and then run exec?

Yes, it should, and you've not presented any reason to think that it doesn't.

`printf` directs output to the standard output stream, and that defaults to being *line buffered* when it is connected to an interactive device, or to being *block buffered* otherwise.  When `execvp()` succeeds, it replaces the whole program image with that of a new program, including the contents of any I/O buffers.  Any data that have been buffered but not flushed to the underlying device are lost.

When `execvp()` fails and the program thereafter terminates normally (regardless of its exit status) all then-buffered buffered data is automatically flushed to the relevant output device.

You would see different behavior if you appended a newline to the message you are printing, or if you called `fflush(stdout)` between the `printf` and `execvp` calls, or if you printed to `stderr` instead of to `stdout`, or if you turned off buffering of `stdout`.